# I have right skewed distribution of a continous variable and it has outliers. Should i replace outliers with mode or median of that column?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have right skewed distribution of a continous variable and it has outliers. Should i replace outliers with mode or median? **my dataset is small (1400 records)**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider posting the question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). I would prefer replacing the outliers with median though.

Comment: as a general advice, provide examples and expected outcome

Comment: thank you so much both of you..john I replaced it with median and my right skewed distribution changed a bit...my mode also changed? I am very new to data science..so please bear with me. Is it the right practice if my mode changed when i replaced outliers with median?